# Android enlarge and shrink image

Tags: android, image

I would enlarge and shrink image when click. Enlarge when click and shrike after 5 second.

I writed this :

```
resimdnm.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

 resimdnm.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

 relativel.bringChildToFront(resimdnm);

SystemClock.sleep(5000);

resimdnm.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Resimdnm is a ImageView
Relativel is a RelativeLayout

When I delete there:

```
SystemClock.sleep(5000);

resimdnm.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The Image enlarge. But when I add sleep fonction. The image doesn’t enlarge.

How can I solve this?

I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
resimdnm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            resimdnm.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            resimdnm.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);


            if (resimdnm.getLayoutParams().height == RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT && resimdnm.getLayoutParams().width == RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        resimdnm.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                }, 5000);

            }

        }
    });
```